# Section numbers aufter section break word with mailmerge

Tags: ms-word

I have a word document and a section break in the middle of my document so that i can switch to landscape format. But the section numbering goes across the entire document. This means that sections 1 to 5 are in portrait format, then there is a section break and sections 6 to 11 are in landscape format. I can simply say "continue numbering" and it runs from 1 to 11 without any problems. However, when I create the documents with mailmerge, it goes from 1 to 5 and then from 1 to 6 again. How can I or can I solve the problem?